# Could I use the ID-based GitHub-provided noreply address in git?

Tags: git, github

Would my contributions be counted if I use the ID-based GitHub-provided noreply address in git as the email and push changes ?

My ID-based GitHub-provided noreply address looks like this `ID+username@users.noreply.github.com`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer?** Yes, your contributions will be counted.

**Longer answer?** Yes, they will be counted, but doing it this way may have ramifications for you in the future. For context, GitHub assigns contributions to accounts by the email address used to `git commit`. <s>Therefore, if you change your GitHub username in the future, your GitHub-assigned email would change, and GitHub won't assign commits from your old GitHub email to your account anymore. (I know from personal experience.) If you're interested in keeping your email private but still having your changes counted, I might recommend attributing your commits to some email that you only use for git, but that you know won't change over time if you ever decide to change your username.</s>

**Edit:** Under the old GitHub system with `username@users.noreply.github.com` emails, the commits would no longer be attributed after you changed your username. Because you have one of the new `ID+username@users.noreply.github.com` email addresses, you'll be fine even after changing username. GoodDeeds' answer notes this correctly.

See [this documentation page](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/setting-your-commit-email-address) for more information about GitHub private email addresses and how to set them up. Also, if you're interested, here is a GitHub [blog post](https://github.blog/2017-04-11-private-emails-now-more-private/) about securing your account further by rejecting pushes that contain a public email.

Comment: But I could see this mentioned "If you use your GitHub-provided noreply email address to make commits and then change your username, those commits will not be associated with your GitHub account. This does not apply if you're using the ID-based GitHub-provided noreply address." at https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/setting-your-commit-email-address

Comment: Edited my answer. That is correct—I had been using one of the old email addresses which is why my change attributions got lost. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: And what if I change my primary email address now ?

Comment: The primary email address in your GitHub account has nothing to do with the auto-generated GitHub email. As long as you make your commits using the ID+username address given to you by GitHub, you can change the primary email address on your GitHub account and your commit attributions should be unaffected.

Comment: And what if I was using my primary email address earlier and now I change my email address, would my contributions be gone ?

Comment: You are allowed to have as many email addresses linked to a GitHub account as you'd like. As long as the email address you originally used to make the commits is still on the account, the commits will stay attributed to you. So you can change which address is marked as "primary" and there will be no effect on your commits, but you can't remove the address which originally made the commits. ([More info](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/adding-an-email-address-to-your-github-account))

Comment: Thanks @a4x for such a great explanation. I hope you liked my question.

Answer (score 3):

Your contributions will be counted by GitHub as usual. Ever since ID-based noreply addresses were introduced, your contributions continue to be counted even if you change your username in the future (unless GitHub changes its policy in the future). The relevant documentation can be found [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/setting-your-commit-email-address), and further explanation is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63697785/5987698).